# Resolution sometimes changes when I switch my monitor back on

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, display-resolution, radeon

I am using Kubuntu 18.04. GPU is a Radeon RX 580. I am using the amdgpu driver. OpenGL renderer string is:

```
Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.23.0, 4.15.0-47-generic, LLVM 7.0.0)
```

So, since this is the amdgpu driver, Mesa3D and KMS are in use.

I have a 4K monitor connected to the RX 580's DisplayPort.

Sometimes, when I started Kubuntu the display off, and later turn it back on, the image isn't the usual 3840x2160 pixels. Instead, sometimes it is 1920x1200, or 640x480 (and shrunken in the vertical direction). In the latter case, I have to turn the monitor off and on again until the resolution is 1920x1200. Then I can go to the display settings and set it back to 3840x2160.

This is very annoying, and I found no indication of any problems anywhere. Does anybody have any idea what is going on?